# Read connection string from web config

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I am building a web application in Framework 4.5.
I want to save my connection string in the web config and to read from there.
For some reason i cant read it.
The web config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdminConnection"     connectionString="DataSource=10.0.0.20;InitialCatalog=MailDB;PersistSecurityInfo=True;UserID=s      a;Password=********;"/>
```

The code

```
using System.Configuration;
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminConnection"];
```

I am getting error on the configuration manager, and i tried all sort of variations.
Thank for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not right. It's stored in your `ConnectionStrings` not your `AppSettings`. [See the MSDN for How to: Read Connection Strings for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using:

```
string connectionString = 
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Your code is trying to read from a non existing `appSettings` section, which is why you are getting errors.

The `connectionStrings` section in the configuration file gets deserialized into the `ConnectionStrings` collection, not into the `AppSettings` collection (the `appSettings` section gets deserialized into that).

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is in your `<appSettings>` ; connection strings are in your `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`.